# Waving hand of figure three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a human-like figure and now I am trying to make the figure wave with his left hand when I click the waveButton.
I created a hierarchy where element body is the parent, and leftArm,rightArm,leftLeg,rightLeg,head are its children.

```
//creating body
var body = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
body.position.set(0,0,0 );

//creating leftArm
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(sizes.armW,sizes.armH,sizes.armD);
var leftArm = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
leftArm.position.set(sizes.bodyW/2 + sizes.armW/2,sizes.bodyH/100,0);


//with this function I am trying to rotate the arm for waving, but the arm is
 rotating like a clock hand, meaning rotating around its middle point.
function waveHand()
{
    leftArm.rotation.z += direction * 0.01;
}
```

How can I edit this function so, the hand would remain attached to the body and wave, instead of getting unattached from the main body and rotating around its center.

Comment: You can use `Math.sin(time)` or `Math.cos(time)` to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using of trigonometric functions:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var box1Geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.25, 2, 0.25);
box1Geom.translate(0, 1, 0);
var box1 = new THREE.Mesh(box1Geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(box1);

var box2Geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.125, 1, 0.125);
box2Geom.translate(0, 0.5, 0);
var box2 = new THREE.Mesh(box2Geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
box2.position.y = 2;
box1.add(box2);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;
var delta = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  time += delta;
  box1.rotation.z = Math.sin(time * 2) * THREE.Math.degToRad(10);
  box2.rotation.z = Math.cos(time * 8) * THREE.Math.degToRad(20) + THREE.Math.degToRad(20);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```